# Unity: One unit hitting another - C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unit and i'm making this hack and slash game.
I'm having trouble with making one unit deal damage to another, though
EDIT: i forgot to mention the hit() method is being called from the animator.

```
public GameObject obj;
```

(...)

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
   if(!collider.gameObject.GetComponent<floor>())
   { 
       obj=collider.gameObject;
       print(obj);
   }
}


void hit()
{
    print(obj);
    if(kicked&&obj)     
    {
        obj.GetComponent<health>().DealDamage(damage);
        print(obj.GetComponent<health>().value);
    }
}
```

the hit() method is being called by the animation (when the kick animation is performed). by the way, when you kick, the bool kicked becomes true. The hit method has been printing (null) every single time.

Comment: First off you're never calling the `hit()` method as far as I can see, secondly, I dont thing the `bool` returned by `GetComponent` indicates if that component exists or not (I could be wrong here).

Maybe add a `floor` tag to the floor and do `if (!collider.gameObject.Tag == "floor"){dostuff();}`

Comment: @james-hughes
I tried the tag suggestion, but i get the error message
[Assets/Scripts/movement.cs(132,77): error CS0023: The `!' operator cannot be applied to operand of type `string']

I forgot to mention above that the hit() method is called from the animator, by the way.
Thanks for the answer, anyway

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part, try `if (!(collider.gameObject.Tag == "floor")){dostuff();}`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
GameObject obj=collider.gameObject;
```

to

```
obj=collider.gameObject;
```

You're declaring a second "obj" variable in your OnTriggerEnter2D method, local to that method, which is overriding the one you declared in your class. I should probably mention that your code (while it may work) is very poorly written. You should read up on OO design patterns.

Comment: I hadn't spotted that

Answer (score 0):

multiple variable with same name .you have declare "obj" as public and than again want to  Declare as local variable .change the name of obj if it is same remove "Gameobject" from inside function .

obj=collider.gameObject;